# What happends if i change the hard drive form HDD to SSD and then again to HDD on an old pc?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, sata, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have a 2010 Lenovo PC sitting around, I dont use it because it is extremly slow
It has a Seagate 160GB 5k RPM SATA HDD, the question is, what if i put an SSD to see what happens, and then i put back the HDD.

It has Windows 10 intalled at the moment

Will the windows stay with all the drivers, or nothing, because if the ssd is much better, i will install win10 on the SSD and have the DATA on the HDD

the specs if needed
DUO E8500
GT 210
5K RPM HDD
4x1GB DDR3
Build-in Case psu 280W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swap the HDD for an SSD, you will have to reinstall everything including the OS.  It will probably be significantly faster.

When you swap the SSD back to the HDD, it will continue from when you last used the HDD.

If you then swap the HDD back to the SSD, it will continue from when you last used the SSD.

Comment: exacly what i asked for, thanks